# Debugging ios5 iPad application on real device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, instruments

I have an application running on the real iPad device.
Randomly, when I click some button (not always the same) the application just quits without any message (it keeps running but ipad returns to home screen).

Instruments doesn't detect any memory leak.

How can I debug this issue and find the real problem? Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: (comment from Tony on a deleted answer) I can't see any crash from my Application. Apparently it is not a crash. I am debugging it directly from XCode. I don't get any error message. Any idea?

Comment: You may want to edit the question to include this information. I am at a complete loss as to what may be going on: every time my program quits like that, I can find a crash log rather reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.

I was using the segue (ios 5 arrow in storyboard builder) to navigate back to another view. I fixed it by navigating using dismiss in an action.

Answer (score 0):

1) Connect real device to the Xcode and debug in the same way, like a simulator in Target Output

2) Open Xcode Organizer (menu Window) and debug in Console or Device Logs.

3) Check the source code in Xcode from menu Product -> Analyze.